# Clear ASP.NET MVC3 browser debug preview in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, browser, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I clear the cache of the web browser in such a way that it will show me the updated page when I run a debug of a ASP.NET MVC3 application in Visual Studio 2010?
Is there some easy way to do it?
The problem is that I'm working on a project and every time I modify something in the CSS style the debug "preview" in the web browser window will not update. Even if I recompile, rebuild the solution and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally press F5 (in the browser) to fully reload the page, and all referenced resources.

This works in any browser I know (IE, FF, Chrome, Opera).